Can a flat roof comfortably carry a 600 lbs load?
We have a traditional three story town home with a flat roof. We want to replace our skylight with a walk-on version. Can the roof carry such load? Specs:

Roof size: 14ft x 28ft.
Skylight size: 50 x 50 inch.
Skylight weight: 600 lbs.
Joists are space 14 inches apart.
Joists are 2 x 12 inch.

There is already existing framing for the current (non walk-on) skylight which has the same dimensions. So the hope is the new one can be dropped in.

If the old one is 600lbs, then I don't see why not, but if it is lighter, we'd need to know how the roof is framed (dimensions of rafters/joists), material used, if they are cross-braced, and their spacing.

It depends more on how the roof was made/ what weight it can hold.

is the current framing attached to the roof rafters ?

@UnhandledExcepSean I just added the joist dimensions (2x12) spaced 14 inches apart.

What snow load is assumed in your area?

The safest approach would be to go to your local government office and get a copy of the construction plans which was submitted for the permit.
From there you can find the roof specifications.
The roof rafters were cut so they lost the original specifications. However it depends how they were framed too compensate for that.
Chances are that the Joists are space 14 inches apart. Joists are 2 x 12 inch are strong enough. But please inspect the framing attachment to the rafters.
Side question: how are you going to bring the 600 pounds to the roof?

Construction plans requested, thanks! We'll be using a crane + suction cups to get the skylight up there.
